# Why do I have to Round summed values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I find that if I don't round the Summed values in the below query, I get a random number with a long decimal value for values that should be 0. When I round it as shown below, this solves the issue. It only affects zero (0) values. Any idea what's going on?!

```
SELECT     
    AccNo, AccType, ROUND(SUM(amount), 4) AS balance
FROM
    TRANS_Table
WHERE     
    (comp = 'XXX') AND (transdate <= @AsAtDate)
GROUP BY 
    AccNo, AccType
ORDER BY 
    AccNo
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of the Amount field ?

Comment: Mmmm...could be due to data type then?

Comment: Data Type is actually Float - this explains it?!